# Setting a text to Bold in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

Heres the particular html code, which consists of the button 'bold' and the text area.

```
<form name="myform">
 < input type="button" onClick="Bold()" value="Bold"> 
</form>

<textarea name="myTextArea" id="myTextArea" cols="100" rows="14" placeholder="Enter Text Here ...">< /textarea>
```

Heres My Javascript

```
function Bold() {
    myTextArea.document.execCommand('bold',false,null); 
}
```

What am i doing wrong ????

Comment: can you explain what is this code `myTextArea.document.execCommand('bold',false,null);` ?

Comment: you can use this too, if you want more functions like Bold, Italic etc http://ckeditor.com/demo

Comment: First of all, I think that would not work because JavaScript doesn't recognize `myTextArea` as an HTML element. You can use a library like `jQuery` in order to easyly recognize elements. Secondly, as @Pilot says, I don't know what `.document.execCommand('bold',false,null);` does. Where did you take that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use javascript like this:

```
function Bold() {
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").style.fontWeight = 'bold'; 
}
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/PmS66/)

Comment: This script applies to the whole textarea, what if you wanted to make a word out of a sentence bold.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the textarea to display bold text, you can do that via css style attribute:

```
<textarea style="font-weight: bold">test-text</textarea>
```

Also, you can use `div` insted, and set `contenteditable="true"` http://jsfiddle.net/XNkDx/2852/ And, use hotkey `ctrl+b`

UPDATE:
If you want to use button, just, get selected text and change it http://jsfiddle.net/XNkDx/2859/

Comment: Thanks, what i'm creating is a word processor and i know i can do it that way. What if i had a sentence and i wanted to make one particular word bold (with a click of a button) rather than going back to re-edit with css ?

Answer (score 0):

I Think you should use string.bold() function of javascript like this one:

```
function Bold() {
    var str = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value();
    var result = str.bold();
}
```

or you can use css style

```
{font-weight:bold;}
```